# How to convert earth-coordinates to astronomical coordinates ?

Tags: python, coordinates, astropy, julian-date

How can I calculate position (ra, dec) of star observed at some station (longitude, latitude) on specific date and time (in julian format)?
I have made some detections in specific days at a specific station, I'd like to convert my earth coordinates to astronomical ones in order to have a map of the sky section I observed.

Comment: Should be on http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/? Certainly, this question has nothing, currently, to do with programming so is off-topic for SO.

Comment: why is my question off-topic? I have to write a program with astropy to convert my data and create a sky map of galaxy. I need a routine to convert julian time and horizontal coordinates to astronomical ones,

Comment: Yes, but you haven't written a program yet. You are asking how to do the conversion which is is a purely mathematical problem. When you have written some code, and if you then do not get the desired result, then show us the code and the specific problem with it and it may be on-topic. For now, in my opinion, it isn't.

Comment: If you reverse the [observation planning example](http://astropy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/coordinates/observing-example.html) at the astropy documentation, you can get what you want.

Comment: @SiHa It probably is on topic, as the OP ask how to convert between coordinate systems *using the astropy software package*. However, the OP hasn't show any effort at attempting this theirselves, which would certainly warrant a down vote.("this question does not show any research effort").

Comment: @Evert. I'll admit that I didn't notice the Astropy tag initially, but my opinion is the same. It is only *my* opinion though.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Astropy documentation, [skycoord](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord.html#astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord) seem to perform what you need.

obstime argument is of type [Time](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.time.Time.html#astropy.time.Time) and can be set in julian format

```
<class 'astropy.time.formats.TimeJulianEpochString'>
```